# PHP form mail and register globals

Tags: global, php

I have a form and php processing file, and everything seems to be working fine except that the user-entered variables are not showing up in the emailed form results. From the research I've done (I'm beginner PHP), I'm guessing it's because my script uses HTTP_POST_VARS and my client's server has globals turned off? They recently switched from Godaddy Windows to Godaddy Linux hosting.

This is my processing file:

```
<?php
        // where is your config file stored?
include ("ajaxSubmit.php");

    // CLIENT INFORMATION

$Contactname = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Contactname'];
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS['email'];
$Contacttitle = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Contacttitle'];
$Business = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Business'];
$Address = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Address'];
$City = $HTTP_POST_VARS['City'];
$State = $HTTP_POST_VARS['State'];
$Zip = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Zip'];
$Phone = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Phone'];
$Fax = $HTTP_POST_VARS['Fax'];
$product_desc = $HTTP_POST_VARS['product_desc'];
$delivery = $HTTP_POST_VARS['delivery'];
$sku = $HTTP_POST_VARS['sku'];
$annualturns = $HTTP_POST_VARS['annualturns'];
$seasonal = $HTTP_POST_VARS['seasonal'];
$minmaxpallet = $HTTP_POST_VARS['minmaxpallet'];
$avgpalletval = $HTTP_POST_VARS['avgpalletval'];
$avgpalletwt = $HTTP_POST_VARS['avgpalletwt'];
$maxpalletht = $HTTP_POST_VARS['maxpalletht'];
$casesperpallet = $HTTP_POST_VARS['casesperpallet'];
$unitweight = $HTTP_POST_VARS['unitweight'];
$reqlotnumctrl = $HTTP_POST_VARS['reqlotnumctrl'];
$freightclass = $HTTP_POST_VARS['freightclass'];
$hazardclass = $HTTP_POST_VARS['hazardclass'];
$barcodes = $HTTP_POST_VARS['barcodes'];
$avgupsfedex = $HTTP_POST_VARS['avgupsfedex'];
$avgorderweight = $HTTP_POST_VARS['avgorderweight'];
$ordersending = $HTTP_POST_VARS['ordersending'];
$custpickups = $HTTP_POST_VARS['custpickups'];
$flatfiles = $HTTP_POST_VARS['flatfiles'];
$shrinkwrap = $HTTP_POST_VARS['shrinkwrap'];
$repack = $HTTP_POST_VARS['repack'];
$specialreq = $HTTP_POST_VARS['specialreq'];


// MODIFY THE FOLLOWING SECTION

// your name
$recipientname = "Company X";

// your email
$recipientemail = "email@email.com";

// subject of the email sent to you
$subject = "Quote Request for $recipientname";

// send an autoresponse to the user?
$autoresponse = "yes";

// subject of autoresponse
$autosubject = "Thank you for your mail!";

// autoresponse message
$automessage = "Thanks for the message. We've successfully received your quote request and will get back to you shortly.";

// thankyou displayed after the user clicks "submit"
$thanks = "Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible.";

// END OF NECESSARY MODIFICATIONS

// format message
$message = "Online-Form Response for $recipientname:
<br>
Contact Name: $Contactname
<br>
Business: $Business
<br>
Email: $email
<br>
Address: $Address
<br>
City: $City
<br>
State: $State
<br>
Zip: $Zip
<br>
Phone: $Phone
<br>
Fax: $Fax
<br>
<br>
<br>
Describe your product(s): $product_desc
<br>
How will your product be delivered?: $delivery
<br>
How many SKU's (items): $sku
<br>
How many turns per year?: $annualturns
<br>
Are your products seasonal?: $seasonal
<br>
Indicate minimum and Maximum pallet levels: $minmaxpallet
<br>
Average value per pallet: $avgpalletval
<br>
Weight of a typical pallet: $avgpalletwt
<br>
Maximum pallet stacking height: $maxpalletht
<br>
Cases per pallet? Or average case size?: $casesperpallet
<br>
Weight of each unit?: $unitweight
<br>
Do you require lot number control?: $reqlotnumctrl
<br>
What freight class?: $freightclass
<br>
Is the product hazardous? If so, what classifications?: $hazardclass
<br>
<br>
<br>
Do you need custom Barcodes made?: $barcodes
<br>
What is the average number of orders shipped via UPS/Fedex?: $avgupsfedex
<br>
What is the average order size in weight?: $avgorderweight
<br>
What is the average number of lines per order?: $avgorderlines
<br>
Will your orders be sent via E-mail, FAX, or other?: $ordersending
<br>
Will you have customer pick ups, and how often?: $custpickups
<br>
Can your company e-mail us flat files?: $flatfiles
<br>
Do your orders need to be shrink wrapped?: $shrinkwrap
<br>
Do you need repackaging?: $repack
<br>
Are there any special requirements that your company may have?: $specialreq
<br>";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Company X <email@email.com>' . "\r\n";


// send mail and print success message
mail($recipientemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($autoresponse == "yes") {
$autosubject = stripslashes($autosubject);
$automessage = stripslashes($automessage);
mail($email,"$autosubject","$automessage","From: $recipientname <$recipientemail>");
}

    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/JavaScript\"> window.location.href = \"thanks_quote.php\";</script>";

?>
```

EDIT: I tested on another server (with globals on), and the form worked fine, but I'm not sure how to rewrite my script so that it does not rely on POST?

Comment: try replacing `$HTTP_POST_VARS` with `$_POST`

Comment: Wow that's some heavy code. Use `$_POST`. Also you may remove `language=\"JavaScript\"` or use `header("Location: thanks_quote.php")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTP_POST_VARS` is now deprecated. Also register_globals is deprecated in 5.3.0 and above. So use `$_POST` instead of `HTTP_POST_VARS`.

Also, instead of last line:

```
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/JavaScript\"> window.location.href = \"thanks_quote.php\";</script>";
```

to redirect to another page, use:

```
header('Location: thanks_quote.php');
```